# Get height of responsive youtube video

Tags: jquery, youtube

I need to get the height of a responsive youtube video. I have tried using jQuery on several different selectors targeting the top levels like .extradiv, #video_background_video_0 and also some of them down within the iframe like $('#video_background_video_0_yt').height()

However, everything turns up null or even 0.2.

How do I get the height of the youtube video please?

```
<div class="extradiv">
<div id="video_background_video_0" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden;">

            <iframe id="video_background_video_0_yt" style="position: absolute; left: 0px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="1349" height="759" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1CXFhQ33_xs?loop=0&amp;start=0&amp;autoplay=0&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.onscreencounselling.com"></iframe>

            </div><div class="edclearer"></div><!-- added to see if I can get a height of video_background_video_0-->
            <!--extradiv--></div>
```

css:

```
.extradiv {
    height:100%;
}

#video_background_video_0 {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}

iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsbin.com/qinaruxune/2/edit?css,js,console,output

I'm just using this Javascript code:

```
var videoContainer = document.querySelector("#video_background_video_0");
console.log(videoContainer.getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

This code takes the element with id *'video_background_video_0'*, and using the function **getBoundingClientRect()** I get the bounding height of the element, which is the element's painted height.

Comment: thanks - that's really helpful and started me off. I wanted to use jQuery so I ended up with  var vidCont = $("#video_background_video_0")[0].getBoundingClientRect();  not quite sure why there's a [0] in there, but it didn't work without it.